# Image loading from url still not fast enough using a background queue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, dispatch-async

I started a background queue to load the image first, and then update the UIImageView's image in the main queue.

```
        int i = 0;
        for (UIImageView *imageView in self.featuredPhotoImageViewCollection) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create("imageQueue", NULL), ^{
                NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[featuredPhotos[i] valueForKey:@"url"]];
                UIImage *image = [UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFURL:url];
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    imageView.image = image;
                });
            });
            i++;
        }
```

However, it is still not fast enough. There is 0.5 - 1 sec delay. Any other suggestion other than using a background queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U are misunderstanding the use of background queue. In your code, iOS will start to execute your background code while leaving the main queue not doing anything until it is finished the background code and then update your image view in the main queue.

Therefore, no matter u use what queue in the background, these will not accelerate your speed.

The normal use of it is
1)showing loading indicator,
2)background queue { do something 
3)main queue{ hide loading indicator & update UI }}

In your case, my suggestion is to show the snapshot of your GIF images as the indicator as a mentioned above. Or you can simply just show the indicator.

Or preload all the GIF images some where else and just show it here. Loading multiple images always takes some time.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a third part library like SDWebImage to use caching, so it can reduce your problem to the first download only. It also have options for priority that you may find usefull.

Or you can download the image before arriving to the view where it's displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If the gif is a large file,and server supported multi-thread download.Then you can try a dispatch_group to download the gif.